# Replication SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

Good afternoon,

I am trying to perform a transactional replication in sql server 2016, and I have the following problem.

The scenario is as follows:

A publisher server and a subscriber server, the transactional replication process runs successfully,
the problem comes when, a failover occurs, the application goes from writing from the publisher server to
write to the subscriber server.

My question is, how should the subscriber server be configured so that when a failover of the publishing node occurs, the data written in the subscriber is replicated later to the publisher.

Should I return to the publisher subscriber, and subscriber to the publisher for this process?

Thank you for reading.
 I will be attentive to your opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactional Replication is not intended as a High Availability/Disaster Recovery solution.  There is no client connectivity support for failover, and it's operationally complex.

You should usually use [AlwaysOn Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) instead.

> how should the subscriber server be configured so that when a failover of the publishing node occurs, the data written in the subscriber is replicated later to the publisher.

Either remove replication and re-create it with the subscriber as the new publisher, or use [Bi-Directional Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/bidirectional-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-2017), or [Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks for your information, it is exactly what I needed.